# Linq returning single item in list part of an object

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following database tables:

```
# account_type table #

id       desc
----------------
1        savings
2        checking 

# account table #

id  account_type_id   Name
--------------------------
1       2             Don
2       1             Henry
3       1             Lisa
4       2             Jenifer
```

I want to write a linq query so that it returns object with collection in it, i.e.

```
desc: Savings { Don, Jenifer }
```

I created these classes:

```
public class acctType
{
    public id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<account> account{ get; set;}
}

public class account
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int account_type_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set;}
}
```

My method in api is calling:

```
public accType Get(int id)
{
    var accounts = (from c in db.account_type
                    where c.p_id == id
                    select new accType
                    {
                        id = c.id,
                        name = c.desc,
                        account = new List<account> { name = c.desc }
                    });
  }
  return accounts.FirstOrDefault()
```

Problem is when I get the account object back it only has single for name i.e

```
dsc: checking { Don }
```

While answer should be Don and Jenifer. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your function Get(int id) actually compile? I have not checked it but looks like the curly braces after new List<account> would expect account objects and not name = c.desc. Also, why would you want to have a List of accounts inside the accountType class?

Comment: So that when i get result I have account type SAVINGS and all the people name who have that account type.

Comment: You could still achieve that without keeping account list inside of accountType. Select using a join on the field acct_type_id among the two classes.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning only FirstOrDefault() item,Change the return statement to

```
return accounts.ToList()
```

Edit:

```
public List<accType> Get(int id)
{
  var accounts = (from c in db.account_type
                        where c.p_id == id
                        select new accType
                        {
                            id = c.id,
                            name = c.desc,
                            account = new List<account>()
                            {
                               name=c.desc
                            }
                        });
   return accounts.ToList()
}
```